# SQL Server 32 bits but SQL Server Management Studio 64 bits, would this work?

Tags: sql-server, 32bit-64bit

I am a student and I benefit from tons of free software, but the site my faculty has a contract with uses "Secure Download Manager" or SDM. It kinda sucks.

I managed to download the 64 bit version of SQL Server Management Studio, only to notice it does not come with the actual server. So next I want to download the server, right ?

Currently I'm trying to download "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 CTP2 32/64-bit (English)" This comes with a choice between 32 / 64 bit versions on the same download. I can chose which I want, but for some reason the SDM is being kinda stupid. It downloaded the 32 bit version in 10 minutes, but almost 2 hours later the 64 bit version is at 20%.

My question is this: would the 64 bit version of SQL Server Management Studio work with a 32 bit server or no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Management studio is just a client, and doesn't care about the "bit-ness" of the server.

Comment: I was almost sure this is the case, but for whatever reason I find installing Microsoft SQL is horrible and I always find a way to break everything, thus I really needed confirmation.